# Odds of Fusion of Chromosome #2

Tags: evolution, molecular-evolution

There is strong evidence that chromosome 2 in humans is a fusion of two chimp chromosomes (i.e. common ancestor of chimps and humans) as explained at wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromosome_2_%28human%29)

The question is what are the odds of a similar event occuring at random in newborns?

I have read conflicting reports, some say these things happen in about 1 out of a 1000 live births, while others placed the odds at somewhere around 1 in 7 billion.

Comment: It`s not the fusion of two chimp chromosomes. To be more precisely - it`s the fusion of two chromosomes in common ancestor (chimp & human).

Comment: Do those "conflicting reports" write about same field: fusion chromosomes in newborns or rearrangements in cancer, or in between species?

Comment: @Pgibas they were estimating the odds of the chromosome 2 fusion happening the way it did in newborns today.

Comment: Robertsonian translocations occur with a frequency of approximately 1 in 1100..

Comment: Would be good to add the references for the conflicting reports.

Comment: @Remi.b couple of articles on line by biologists. not creationists. offhand cant remember the sites.